# SQL query returning only record that two words

Tags: sql

I am trying to query out only the records from the data (shown below) that have only two words in the column "species". I don't want any that have more or less than this, so I only have true species left.

species
Acanthis cabaret
Acanthis flammea
Aix

I can't work out how to do this

Comment: You could add a specie having three words too. And also _specify_ the expected result. And add a tag for the dbms used (very possible product specific functionality will be used). And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: And, one more thing, tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Do you really need RDBMS name here?

Comment: @SomendraKanaujia Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms if you don't know why the RDBMS is important.

Comment: @JonasMetzler here is already `SQL` tag mentioned and as I read your link they also mentioned for Good answer we can add RDBMS Tag but it is not Mandatory. in same link in comments you need to read that `Please don't downvote questions asked in good faith; it's unhelpful. It pushes the question off of the front page (and only findable using arcane magic) and it discourages meta participation by newcomers to meta.`

Comment: No idea why you tell me about up - or downvoting questions. I did not vote on this question. Anyway, lots of functions differ depending on the RDBMS, for example `LEN` or `LENGTH`. One way to solve the question would be to use one of them. That's why jarlh and me asked about the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep it simple and use the `LIKE` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE species LIKE '% %' AND     -- one space present => 2 words
      species NOT LIKE '% % %';  -- but not 3 or more words
```

Comment: What will happen if there is any space in starting of string like ` 1stWord`